# What are the expected behavior and characteristics of a currency input?

Tags: input-fields, input

I'm trying to make a list of the expected behavior and characteristics of a user textbox when it is designed for currency or money input.

**Characteristics:**

- Numeric only.
- With two decimal places.
- With currency sign.
- With thousands separator.

**Expected behavior should be:**

- When the user types in, it should automatically format the value with the expected characteristics.
- As the user continues typing, the input should continue formatting the value with the expected characteristics. But while doing it, the cursor should be placed into the expected position.
- On copy-paste command, it should remove all non-numeric values and replace or add only the correct value into the textbox. (I'm not sure if this is correct)

In the expected behavior, the second one, I wanted to have a more technical understanding of how the cursor should behave. For example, as the user types in and the formatting is being executed, where should the cursor be positioned?

I am thinking of the following behavior, I am not sure if this is how it should be.

For example, if I entered `1` in an empty textbox then it should automatically format the textbox to `1.00`. However, the cursor should remain at the end of the last entered digit, in this case, it should be `1[cursor should be here].00`.

Also, is there any other expected behavior aside from these three and other characteristics?

I made a simple implementation of this using HTML/jQuery for more details, this isn't complete yet, for demonstration purposes only. [Currency Input Demo](https://codepen.io/poralcode/pen/oNQQQyp)

Comment: I'm having trouble envisioning what you mean by "the cursor should be placed into the expected position". Can you provide some screenshots/videos on what the behavior might be?

Comment: @LeoWattenberg I added more context and a demo for more details. Please see the updated question.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that you're running into the messiness of languages, currencies, and region locales here. Sometimes it's as simple as periods and commas changing meaning. Wikipedia has [a list of examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Examples_of_use) for different number formats, and you may run into someone expecting their input of 1億2345萬6789 (Chinese) or 12,34,567.89 (Indian) to be parsed.

Further, according to [ISO 4217](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217#List_of_ISO_4217_currency_codes), some currencies have no decimals, most have 2, but some have 3 or 4.

You're signing up for a world of hurt here if you try to do some clever UX on these.

The safest pattern I've found here is a humble dropdown as the currency selector with a plain text box as the number input, and then a second step which confirms back to the user how that number they just entered got parsed. To be clear, it's possible to envision and implement a better UX than this, however the stakes are much higher than for most other UX tasks - If you end up with a customer who accidentally sent 1000€ instead of 10,00€ because your system didn't interpret comma as a decimal separator, you'll feel the wrath very fast.

Comment: I figured that too. I think I will limit my scope to the most common currency only which contains only two decimal places. I'll study further later on how to solve that when I understand and figure out my first requirement. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Btw, if you are on web, there's an [Internationalisation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat) that does all the work for you.